# Non modal UserForm and Workbook navigation

Tags: excel, vba

Very specific problem not related directly to code but more to Excel behavior.

When launching a non modal `UserForm` (`vbmodeless`) from a minimized `WorkBook` (not visible on screen), while another `WorkBook` is on screen, Excel will "link" this `UserForm` and its focus to the visible one. This means that minimizing or maximizing the second `WorkBook` will hide and show the `UserForm`, but doing so with the first `WorkBook` won't, even if it has been launched by the first `WorkBook`.
Worse, closing the second `WorkBook` will close the `UserForm`.

An example of the issue :

```
Sub TestSo()
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    UFTest.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Just create an empty `UserForm` named UFTest, open 2 Workbooks and display them split mode on screen and then call this Sub. You'll see that the `UserForm` is now linked to the wrong `WorkBook`.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Instead of minimizing you could  position the workbook out of the viewable screen boundaries (either negative or higher coordinates) and provide for a re-positioning routine. Didn't try, so please verify if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do the trick?

```
Sub TestSo()
    UFTest.Show vbModeless
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
End Sub
```

Then in Userform restore the visibility

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```